# JQuery not working in Firefox, does in Safari

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm building a site using Jquery for some basic animation. The javascript is here:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);
var currentSelection = null;
var previousSelection = null;
function initialize()
{

$("#print").bind("mouseover", navHover);
$("#print").bind("mouseout", navStby);
$("#print").bind("click", selectPrint);

$("#radio").bind("mouseover", navHover);
$("#radio").bind("mouseout", navStby);
$("#radio").bind("click", selectRadio);

$("#tv").bind("mouseover", navHover);
$("#tv").bind("mouseout", navStby);
$("#tv").bind("click", selectTV);

$("#comedy").bind("mouseover", navHover);
$("#comedy").bind("mouseout", navStby);
$("#comedy").bind("click", selectComedy);

$("#about").bind("mouseover", navHover);
$("#about").bind("mouseout", navStby);
$("#about").bind("click", selectAbout);
}

function navHover(){
    $(this).css({"background-position":"0px 124px"});
}

function navStby(){
    $(this).css({"background-position":"0px 0px"});
}

function selectPrint()
{
    if(currentSelection==null)
    {
        $("#print").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500, loadPrint);
}
else if(currentSelection!=null)
{
    $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"-450"}, 1000, loadPrint);
    currentSelection.animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 500);
    $("#print").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500);
}

}

function loadPrint()
{
    currentSelection = $("#print");
    $("#titleContainer").css({"background":"url('img/printTitle.png')",         "background-repeat":"no-repeat"});
    $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 1000);
}



function selectRadio()
{
    if(currentSelection==null)
    {
        $("#radio").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500, loadRadio);
    }
    else if(currentSelection!=null)
    {
            $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"-450"}, 1000, loadRadio);
        currentSelection.animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 500);
        $("#radio").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500);
    }

}

function loadRadio()
{
    currentSelection = $("#radio");
    $("#titleContainer").css({"background":"url('img/radioTitle.png')", "background-repeat":"no-repeat"});
    $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 1000);
}



function selectTV()
{
    if(currentSelection==null)
    {
        $("#tv").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500, loadTV);
    }
    else if(currentSelection!=null)
    {
        $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"-450"}, 1000, loadTV);
        currentSelection.animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 500);
        $("#tv").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500);
    }

}

function loadTV()
{
    currentSelection = $("#tv");
    $("#titleContainer").css({"background":"url('img/tvTitle.png')", "background-repeat":"no-repeat"});
    $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 1000);
}


function selectComedy()
{
    if(currentSelection==null)
    {
        $("#comedy").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500, loadComedy);
    }
    else if(currentSelection!=null)
    {
        $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"-450"}, 1000, loadComedy);
        currentSelection.animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 500);
        $("#comedy").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500);
    }

}

function loadComedy()
{
    currentSelection = $("#comedy");
    $("#titleContainer").css({"background":"url('img/comedyTitle.png')", "background-repeat":"no-repeat"});
    $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 1000);
}

function selectAbout()
{
    if(currentSelection==null)
    {
        $("#about").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500, loadAbout);
    }
    else if(currentSelection!=null)
    {
        $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"-450"}, 1000, loadAbout);
        currentSelection.animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 500);
        $("#about").animate({"margin-left":"-40px"}, 500);
    }

}

function loadAbout()
{
    currentSelection = $("#about");
    $("#titleContainer").css({"background":"url('img/aboutTitle.png')", "background-repeat":"no-repeat"});
    $("#titleContainer").animate({"margin-left":"0px"}, 1000);
}
```

I know that's a lot. Here's the html too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
</div>
<div id="titleStrip">
    <div id="titleContainer">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="print">
</div>
<div id="radio">
</div>
<div id="tv">
</div>
<div id="comedy">
</div>
<div id="about">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the CSS:

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#372D23;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande";
    overflow:hidden;
}

#logo
{
    background:url("img/logo.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-top:0;
    float:right;
    width:440px;
    height:240px;
}
#comedy
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/comedyBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#tv
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/tvBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#about
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/aboutBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#print
{
        height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/printBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#radio
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/radioBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#titleStrip
{
    background:url("img/titleBackground.png");
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#titleContainer
{
    width:450px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-450px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

This works fine both locally and on the server in Safari 4, but neither locally or on server for Firefox 3.5.5. Actually let me be more specific. The Hover over sprites for #print, #radio, #tv, #comedy and #about work fine in Firefox, what doesn't work is the click event which is supposed to initiate the animation. If any more explanation is necessary, I'd be glad to elaborate.

I've spent about an hour online looking for a solution and haven't found one. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: could you show your stylesheet ?

Comment: Its hard to troubleshoot without the CSS + Images. Can you upload to a location for us to test? I haven't been able to find a *problem* with your code yet. I do have some suggestions for making it shorter, but I want to solve the problem first.

Comment: sure thing:

http://shadystudios.org/jackpacheco

I'll add the CSS in a sec.

Comment: okay, CSS is up too. Thanks for taking the time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is because Firefox isn't animating the "margin-left" property on your objects. If you change them to `left` it works as expected.

**Re-factoring tip:**

You can get rid of all your `bind('mouse...` calls with this one line:

```
$("#print, #radio, #tv, #comedy, #about").hover(navHover, navStby);
```

Ideally you should do that part in pure CSS, with this code as a fallback for IE6 only. (`:hover` on a `div` works in IE7+, Firefox, and Safari)

**Further Refactoring:**

Take it or leave it, but here is a refactored version that uses all the same CSS as your original. Your site is coming along nicely. I really like the tab and title thing you have going!

Refactored `javascript.js` file: https://gist.github.com/471ab8a968b1394a359e

Comment: Halfway there! Okay so I changed all "margin-left" to "left". Now the tabs on the left side are animated, but the title (#titleContainer) still isn't sliding in from the right. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you still have the negative `margin-left` set in your stylesheet. Change that from `margin-left: -450px` to `left: -450px` and you will be golden.

Comment: Golden indeed! Thank you sir, you have been of tremendous help. I'll take a look at your tip as well, see if I can get that working. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating way way to much code.

First thing first add class="nav-button" to all your nav buttons.

Rather then repeating code multiple times to do almost the same thing create function that are smart enough to know what to do in all states.

```
$(document).ready(initialize);
var currentSelection = null;
var previousSelection = null;
function initialize(){
    $('.nav-button').hover(navHover, navStby)
    .bind("click", selectArea);
}
function navHover(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}
function navStby(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
}
function selectArea(){
    if(!currentSelection){
        $(this).animate({"left":"-40px"}, 500, loadArea);
    } else {
        $("#titleContainer").animate({"left":"-450"}, 1000);
        currentSelection.animate({"left":"0px"}, 500);
        $(this).animate({"left":"-40px"}, 500, loadArea);
    }
}
function loadArea(){
    var class = this.id;
    currentSelection = $(this);
    $("#titleContainer").removeClass('print radio tv comedy about')
    .addClass(class)
    .animate({'left':'0'}, 1000);
}
```

This code makes it so that you use css for the things that css does best, styling.  Make this your css

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#372D23;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande";
    overflow:hidden;
}

#titleContainer{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


#logo
{
    background:url("img/logo.png");
    position:relative;
    margin-top:0;
    float:right;
    width:440px;
    height:240px;
}
#comedy
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/comedyBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#tv
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/tvBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#about
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/aboutBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#print
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/printBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#radio
{
    height:124px;
    width:45px;
    background:url("img/radioBtn.png");
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#titleStrip
{
    background:url("img/titleBackground.png");
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    left:0px;
}

#titleContainer
{
    width:450px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-450px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.nav-button.hover{
    background-position: 0px 124px !important;
}
.print{
    background-image: url('img/printTitle.png');
}
.radio{
    background-image: url('img/radioTitle.png');
}
.tv{
    background-image: url('img/tvTitle.png');
}
.comedy{
    background-image: url('img/comedyTitle.png');
}
.about{
    background-image: url('img/aboutTitle.png');
}
```

Comment: Tried this, the result is still the same, though with less code. Still having [lack of] animation issues. Also, the hover states are now broken. I tried changing all the print, radio, tv, comedy and about classes back to ids (assuming that's what you meant), but no dice. Thoughts?

Comment: Nice example code! I would do one more step and change `bind('mouseover')` and `bind('mouseout')` to `.hover(navHover, navStby)`